# Safari CSS3 3D animate transformed intersecting elements flicker issue

Tags: css, 3d, safari, transform, css-transitions

I made a wedding invitation and there's a code at the bottom of the invitation to log into the wedding website. To make people aware of the code I created a little CSS3 3D animation: [see the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/manu_miu/rbgt4/12/)

**HTML:**

```
<section id="viewport">
    <div id="invitation" class="show-front">
        <figure class="front"></figure>
        <figure class="ring"></figure>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
section#viewport {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 0% 0%;
}

div#invitation {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
}

#invitation .front  {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(12deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, 32px);

#invitation .ring {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translate3d(6px, -15px, -1px);
}

#invitation.show-front  {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-24deg) rotateX(90deg);
}

#invitation:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(20deg) rotateX(3deg);
}
```

In Chrome and Firefox looks everything well, but in Safari the intersecting elements produce an annoying flicker issue. If I remove the rings which are intersecting the front picture element the flicker issue don't appear: [the demo without rings](http://jsfiddle.net/rbgt4/11/)

I've tried everything and read every post I could find, but nothing solved this problem. All useless html elements in the demo aren't useless in my real animation.

Comment: -1 for trying to work around the "jsfiddle must be accompanied by code," I will only undo my downvote/answer this question if you actually post the code here

Comment: if you explain what I have to do, I would like to do it. It's my first post and I'm not a native english speaker. I'm sorry.

Comment: Put the code in your question!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't get it. I had too much code to insert in my question.

Comment: Only insert the relevant code.

Comment: Ok, now everything should be right. Tell me if there are still mistakes.